# google JS input tools (transliteration) not working

Tags: android, transliteration, google-input-tools

I am developing a website with Google input tools API.
The transliteration api is not working on android devices.it is working fine on iOS devices and desktop devices. (did not test on windows mobile)

[Google input tools link](https://www.google.lk/inputtools/try/)

even the above link (Google hosted) is not working in android devices. I am using "Sihala" language. I know that the API is deprecated, but is there any way I can get this working on android devices?

Comment: I did search everywhere, but found no solution for this

Answer (score 0):

mostly it looks like it's an issue with keyboard input and not the platform itself like android or ios.

in case you connect a physical keyboard to your android mobile , it will work but not with the android keyword.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).